# What user must own apache log directory

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

If I define apache log directory for a vhost, what is the user that I should make the owner? Should be apache user, or can be root?

Comment: Same permissions as the (global, default) apache log directory

Comment: See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/security_tips.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment elsewhere, apache (in most configurations) starts as root - and root can write anywhere. Allowing the directory to be writeable by the User configured for the webservr is potentially a security hole.

Read access should be limited to people who need to read te logs.

"ownership" is merely a tool for implementing the specifics of the policy.